# PHP stored procedure parameters

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mysqli

I have created a test database as follows:

```
USE test;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS testparams;
CREATE TABLE test
(
  inparm INT,
  inoutparam INT,
  outparm INT
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES (0, 0, 0);

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE testparams(IN i INT, INOUT io INT, OUT o INT)
BEGIN
   UPDATE test SET inoutparm = io + 1, outparm = FLOOR(RAND() * 1000)
               WHERE inparm = i; 

   SELECT outparm INTO o FROM test WHERE inparm = i;
   SELECT inoutparam INTO io FROM test WHERE inparm = i;

END $$
```

I have also got a PHP script:

```
<?php

$c = new mysqli('localhost', 'test', 'test', 'test') or die('Cannot connect');
echo "Connected\n";

$in = 0;
$out = -1;
$inout = 3;

echo "In: $in Out: $out: Inout: $inout\n";

$s = $c->prepare('CALL testparams(?, ?, ?)') or die('Unable to prepare: ' . $c->error);
$s->bind_param('iii', $in, $inout, $out);
#$s->bind_result($out, $inout);
$s->execute();

echo "After execute SP\nIn: $in Out: $out: Inout: $inout\n";

echo "End of SP\n";
$s = $c->prepare('SELECT inparm, inoutparam, outparm FROM test');

# $s->bind_result($in, $inout, $out); - Get a error here

$s->execute();
while ($s->fetch())
{
    echo "In: $in Out: $out: Inout: $inout\n";
}

?>
```

My problem is that the stored procedure does not appear to be called. Is this due to using `OUT` and `INOUT` parameters? If so how do you use these parameters with PHP?

This is demonstrated by the script generating the following output

```
Connected
In: 0 Out: -1: Inout: 3
End of SP
In: 0 Out: 0: Inout: 0
```

Comment: You probably meant

SELECT inoutparam INTO io FROM test WHERE inparm = i;

where it's INTO io rather than INTO o.

Comment: Thanks - Made the change - My mistake. But still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **[CALL Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/call.html)**
>
> For programs written in a language that provides a MySQL interface,
>   **there is no native method for directly retrieving the results of OUT
>   or INOUT parameters from CALL statements.** To get the parameter values,
>   pass user-defined variables to the procedure in the CALL statement and
>   then execute a SELECT statement to produce a result set containing the
>   variable values. To handle an INOUT parameter, execute a statement
>   prior to the CALL that sets the corresponding user variable to the
>   value to be passed to the procedure.

That seems to be changed in MySQL 5.6

> In MySQL 5.6, C programs can use the prepared-statement interface to
>   execute CALL statements and access OUT and INOUT parameters. ...
>   **Languages that provide a MySQL interface can use prepared CALL
>   statements to directly retrieve OUT and INOUT procedure parameters.**

That will do it

```
<?php

$c = new mysqli('localhost', 'test', 'test', 'test') or die('Cannot connect');
echo "<pre>Connected<br>";

$in = 0;
$out = -1;
$inout = 3;

echo "Before executing SP<br>In: $in Inout: $inout Out: $out<br>";

$s = $c->prepare('SET @i = ?, @io = ?') or die('Unable to prepare: ' . $c->error);
$s->bind_param('ii', $in, $inout);
$s->execute();

$s = $c->prepare("CALL testparams(@i, @io, @o)") or die('Unable to prepare: ' . $c->error);
$s->execute();

$s = $c->prepare('SELECT @io, @o');
$s->execute();
$s->bind_result($inout, $out);
$s->fetch();

echo "After execute SP<br>In: $in Inout: $inout Out: $out<br>";

echo "End of SP<br></pre>";

?>
```

Output

```
Connected
Before executing SP
In: 0 Inout: 3 Out: -1
After execute SP
In: 0 Inout: 4 Out: 851
End of SP
```

BTW, there is a typo in SP. This line

```
UPDATE test SET inoutparm = io + 1, outparm = FLOOR(RAND() * 1000)
```

should be

```
UPDATE test SET inoutparam = io + 1, outparm = FLOOR(RAND() * 1000)
                        ^
```

Comment: Those are the tables column names - That bit works and retrieves the tables contents. The bit that does not work is calling the SP.

Comment: Not really - the server is not 5.6. But a valiant effort. I have sort of though of a possible solution though.

Comment: I will have another look at it later on today. Perhaps I have done something wrong in my code (that is a bit more complex than the example). Anyway off to work through the snow.

Comment: Ok. Best of luck. Let me know. Your example and another my example are working just fine on my machine passing in and out everything correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I think `$s->bind_param('sss', $in, $inout, $out`); should be

`$s->bind_param('iii', $in, $inout, $out)`;

Comment: Oops - Amir - Thanks. Updated the change - I was constructing from a more complex example. But after that change the out/inout parameters do not change.

Answer (score 0):

The 'sss' should be 'iii' since you're dealing with integers, not strings.

Comment: I have made an update - but the out/inout params of the stored procedure does not work.